# Parsing text file into csv. Issue splitting string that spans across multiple lines via PowerShell regex

Tags: regex, powershell, export-to-csv, regex-group

I'm attempting to parse a txt file into a csv with 4 headers. However, I'm having some troubles successfully splitting/matching text between two strings that spans across multiple lines. I'm not very experienced with regex. Is there a way to do this without regex? Or does anyone know which combination of regex expressions I could use here?

I started with the following code but welcome any suggestions/recommendations if there's a better way to go about this:

```
$input = Get-Content ‘C:\Example.txt’
$output = ‘C:\Example.csv’
$regex = "'PRINT(.*?\n)PRINT'"
$regex2 = "'INSERT' -or $_ -eq 'UPDATE'"
$matches = [regex]::Matches($input, $regex)::multiline
$array = @()    

$matches | for each-object{
    $write-object = False
    $obj = New-Object System.Object
        If $_ -match $regex
    }
If ($writeobj){
    $obj | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name row1 -value $row
    $array += $obj
}
$array | Export-csv -path $output
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT:**

| SECTION | UPDATE/INSERT | TABLE | CHANGE BLOCK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA | UPDATE | Table_1 | COL_1 = ‘123’ WHERE ID= ‘1’ |
| BB | INSERT | Table_2 | (DBO.COL_1) SELECT Col1Value AS [Col_1] FROM Table_1 |
| CC | UPDATE | Table_1 | COL_3 |
| CC | INSERT | Table_2 | (DBO.COL_3) SELECT Col3Value AS [Col_3] FROM Table_2 |

**EXAMPLE .TXT CONTENT:**

> ```
> --AA***************************
> --PRINT AA
> UPDATE Table_1 
> SET COL_1 = '123'
> WHERE ID = '1'
>
> --BB***************************
> --PRINT BB
> INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table_2] (DBO.COL_1)
> SELECT Col1Value AS [Col_1] 
> FROM  Table_1  
>
> --CC***************************
> --PRINT CC
> UPDATE Table_1 
> SET COL_3 = 'ABC'
> WHERE ID = '3' 
> AND ID2 = '1a' 
>
> INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table_2] (DBO.COL_3)
> SELECT Col3Value AS [Col_3] 
> FROM  Table_2
> ```

Comment: Your code mostly doesn't work. Is there any uniformity to the data set your reading in or does it look like your example ?

Comment: The text file looks like the example text file. Each section is divided by a string "--AA*****************" (whereas AA varies, but is always two characters), otherwise, no uniformity. Each sub-section begins with "INSERT INTO" or "UPDATE".

Comment: You may try to use [ConvertFrom-String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-string?view=powershell-5.1). Here is a good explanation how it works: [Weltner Sophisitcated Techniques of Plain Text Parsing](https://youtu.be/Hkzd8spCfCU?t=1398)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to read the entire file in as a multi-line string using the `-Raw` switch parameter. Then you can split the file by sections (AA, BB, etc) and parse each section with regex. I do a bunch of `-replace` to strip out just the info I want for each property here.

```
$input = Get-Content 'C:\Example.txt'
$output = 'C:\Example.csv'
$array = $input -split '(?ms)(?=--[^\*^\r^\n]+?\*{3,}[^\*])'|%{
    $Record = $_ -replace '(?ms)^--([^\*]+)\*.+$','$1'
    Switch -RegEx (($_ -split '(?ms)(?=UPDATE|INSERT)')){
        '^UPDATE' {[PSCustomObject]@{SECTION=$Record;'UPDATE/INSERT'='UPDATE';TABLE=$_ -replace '(?ms)UPDATE (.+?)[\r\n].*','$1';'CHANGE BLOCK'=$_ -replace 'UPDATE.+?[\r\n]+' -replace '[\r\n]+',' ' -replace '^SET '}}
        '^INSERT' {[PSCustomObject]@{SECTION=$Record;'UPDATE/INSERT'='INSERT';TABLE=$_ -replace '(?ms)INSERT INTO \S+?\[([^\]]+)].*','$1';'CHANGE BLOCK'=$_ -replace '(?ms)INSERT INTO \S+?\[([^\]]+)]\s*' -replace '[\r\n]+',' '}}
    }
}
$array | Export-csv -path $output
```

That provided me with:

```
SECTION UPDATE/INSERT TABLE    CHANGE BLOCK                                             
------- ------------- -----    ------------                                             
AA      UPDATE        Table_1  COL_1 = '123' WHERE ID = '1'                             
BB      INSERT        Table_2  (DBO.COL_1) SELECT Col1Value AS [Col_1]  FROM  Table_1   
CC      UPDATE        Table_1  COL_3 = 'ABC' WHERE ID = '3'  AND ID2 = '1a'             
CC      INSERT        Table_2  (DBO.COL_3) SELECT Col3Value AS [Col_3]  FROM  Table_2
```

Comment: Very nicely done.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar approach to [TheMadTechnician](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3245749/themadtechnician)'s answer, but different enough and since I did the work I figured I'd post it. Suggest the same thing, read the file as one string and split into chunks and process

```
$text = Get-Content C:\Example.txt -Raw
$csvpath = 'Some\Path\To\file.csv'

$splitpattern = '--.+?\*{4,}.+?\r?\n\s*'
$mainpattern = '(?s)(?<Action>INSERT|UPDATE)\s.*?(?<Table>\w{1,}_\d{1,})(\s|]|\r?\n)(?<Change>.+)'
$sectionpattern = '(?s)--Print (?<Section>.+?)\r?\n(?<Remainder>.+)'

$output = $text -split $splitpattern | ForEach-Object {
    if($_ -match $sectionpattern){
        $section,$remainder = $matches.Section,$matches.Remainder

        foreach($block in $remainder -split '(?=UPDATE|INSERT)'){
            if($block -match $mainpattern) {
                [PSCustomObject]@{
                    Section = $section
                    Action  = $matches.Action
                    Table   = $matches.Table
                    Change  = $matches.Change -replace '\r?\n',' '
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

# inspect the output
$output | Out-GridView

# export output
$output | Export-Csv -Path $csvpath -NoTypeInformation
```

The output as a table

```
Section Action Table   Change                                                     
------- ------ -----   ------                                                     
AA      UPDATE Table_1  SET COL_1 = '123' WHERE ID = '1'                          
BB      INSERT Table_2  (DBO.COL_1) SELECT Col1Value AS [Col_1]  FROM  Table_1    
CC      UPDATE Table_1  SET COL_3 = 'ABC' WHERE ID = '3'  AND ID2 = '1a'          
CC      INSERT Table_2  (DBO.COL_3) SELECT Col3Value AS [Col_3]  FROM  Table_2
```